# How to find a component of one column in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck trying to figure out why I am unable to locate something in a pandas data frame. This is where I am stuck:

```py
area_codes = "area_codes.csv"

contacts = 'leads.csv'

df_contacts = pd.read_csv(contacts, header=0)

df_areas = pd.read_csv(area_codes, header=0)


for i in df_contacts['Phone']:
if type(i) is str:
    if str(i[0:3]) in df_areas['Areas']:
        print('Found.')
    else:
        print('Not Found.')
else:
    pass
```

This line in particular is where my question is:

```
if str(i[0:3]) in df_areas['Areas']:
```

What I am *attempting* to do is see if the first 3 digits of a phone number `str(i[0:3])` is in the list of known area codes `df_areas['Areas']`.

For whatever reason I cannot figure out why every check is coming up as false? I also went as far as doing some list comprehension and check it that way. Example: `a = [i for i in df_areas['Areas']]` and then loop over this list.

I've made sure to cast the value to a string so they are both the same object type as originally I thought that was the issue. Which brings me here. I'm just lost at this point. I'm new to programming and just really write little scripts like this that I'll use once or twice. It doesn't need to be performant at all, it just needs to work. So, why is this not working? And just to get ahead of it; yes, I checked to see if there were actually matches.

All the phone numbers in the area code list are 3 digits. Example (fake numbers):

```
1       2014029520
2       2349212706
3       2394944200
4       5166867073
...
Name: Phone, Length: 4305, dtype: object
```

All the phone numbers in the contacts list are 10 digits (or blank lines) with no spaces. Example:

```
0      201
1      202
2      203
3      204
4      205
      ... 
401    980
402    984
403    985
404    986
405    989
Name: Areas, Length: 406, dtype: int64
```

I am casting the values to strings (which I think I'm doing correctly) but I've included the Pandas DF information like the dtype if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- With `codes` and `numbs` starting as integers
- Use `.astype(str)` to cast the columns as `str` type, and then use `.str` methods to determine if the first 3 characters of `numbers` is in a list of [`.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) codes.

  - [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)
  - [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)
  - [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)
  - [Pandas: Working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#working-with-text-data)
  - If the column of `numbers` or `codes` is already a `str` type, `.astype(str)` is not needed.
- `codes.codes.astype(str).unique()` creates a list of unique `codes`, where each value is a `str` type.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
codes = pd.DataFrame({'codes': [201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 980, 984, 985, 986, 989]})

numbs = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [2014029520, 2349212706, 2394944200, 5166867073]})

# vectorized comparison
numbs['valid code'] = numbs.numbers.astype(str).str[:3].isin(codes.codes.unique())

# display(numbs)
      numbers  valid code
0  2014029520        True
1  2349212706       False
2  2394944200       False
3  5166867073       False
```

### With your function

```py
for i in numbs.numbers:
    i = str(i)  # convert the number to a string
    if i[:3] in codes.codes.astype(str).unique():
        print('Found.')
    else:
        print('Not Found.')

[out]:
Found.
Not Found.
Not Found.
Not Found.
```

### If `numbs` is multiple columns and contains `NaN`s

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to test multiple columns.

```py
import numpy as np

# test data
codes = pd.DataFrame({'codes': [201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 980, 984, 985, 986, 989]})

numbs = pd.DataFrame({'leads1': [2014029520, 2349212706, 2394944200, 5166867073, np.nan], 'leads2': [2014029520, 2349212706, 2394944200, 5166867073, np.nan]})

# cast the dataframe as str type
codes = codes.astype(str)
numbs = numbs.astype(str)

# use apply to test all columns
valid = numbs.apply(lambda x: x.str[:3].isin(codes.codes.astype(str).unique()))

# display(valid)
   leads1  leads2
0    True    True
1   False   False
2   False   False
3   False   False
4   False   False
```

### Loading from CSV and Implementation

- Added per question from comment.
- Set the column `dtype` when reading data from the CSV.

```py
# load data from csv
df_contacts = pd.read_csv('leads.csv', dtype={'Phone': str}, header=0)
df_areas = pd.read_csv('area_codes.csv', dtype={'Areas': str} header=0)

# remove any duplicate values
df_areas = df_areas.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

# create a column with True or False
df_contacts['phone_valid_bool'] = df_contacts.Phone.str[:3].isin(df_areas.Areas.to_list())
```